# Are adab questions too open ended, or listy?

Tags: discussion

Consider my question https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/1243/44 . It had some disagreement as not being a good fit for QA format. You can see the comments below it, and also the transcript of the discussion on chat [here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5236268#5236268)

I think it is a good and on-topic because adab is part of the islam. A question like mine can be answered by saying "Prophet (s.a.v) advised this to its followers". On the other hand, [manishearth](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31768/manishearth) says question is still have a make-a-list aspect. What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

Textbook answer from the FAQ definition: questions that are too broad, open-ended, and listy, are not a good fit for the SE site. (They may be good questions, but not for us.)

Remember, the goal is to have a site with a razor-sharp focus: very specific questions and very specific answers. Adab isn't quite like that.

Asking "how can I have fun" vs.  asking "how does Islam ask me to treat someone in X situation" is completely different. Project Management's SE favours the latter type of question, because it's very specific, even though it's an adab question. For example, "[How To Manage Inactive Team Members In A Non-Professional Environment?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5946/how-to-manage-inactive-team-members-in-a-non-professional-environment)"

So adab questions are okay. They need to be focused specifically though instead of being open. Imagine if someone asked "how can I relax in Islam?" What kind of useful answer would any of us actually be able to give?

Answer (score 4):

So that people don't have to wade through chat, let me put my thoughts here:

In its current form, it had two issues:

### Subjectivity

The post looks like it is asking for opinions. (For example, [HaLabi's answer](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/1247/227) is opinionated--not exactly his fault). Such posts ought to be discouraged: While opinions have value, they're not really a good fit for the network.

### Broad

The post is also like a make-a-list question. These are discouraged as well:

[What's the opinion on "list" questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11760/whats-the-opinion-on-list-questions/11771#11771)

[What about a multi-answer question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9782/what-about-a-multi-answer-question) (Note that Community wiki [is discouraged now](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/))

---

The question basically falls under Not Constructive:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

If you had explicitly specified "What does the Prophet say about X", it *may* have been much less broad. (I don't know, though, it still could be make-a-list). Regardless, it wouldn't be opinionated then.

Comment: Instinctive +1 for "Community wiki is discouraged now".  And for the rest of the answer too.